# How to merge multiple c# Projects with same default namespace but different assembly names

Tags: c#, dll, merge, namespaces, assembly-name

i am migrating my old code from VB6 to .net(C#). after rewriting code modules and testing them now started  making my application.

i have multiple projects in my solution( Like Framework ). compiler giving Dll files for each project. i want to merge all projects in to one project so that i can use one Dll file. How to do that.

My Project Details :

> Project 1 : Windows Application ( which uses all Class Library references)
>
> Project 2 : Class Library  Assembly Name : MyApp.UI.Design
> Project 3 : Class Library  Assembly Name : MyApp.UI.Design.Themes
> Project 4 : Class Library  Assembly Name : MyApp.UI.Design.Controllers
> Project 4 : Class Library  Assembly Name : MyApp.UI.Design.xyz

and so on....
total 27 class Library Projects

- Default NameSpace : *MyApp.UI*   for all Class Library Projects  in different locations.

I am using them by adding reference to them in my Application.
I want to merge all Class Library projects into One Project so that i can use only one Dll file instead of multiple Dll Files.

Detailed Code Sample Project or Code Snippet  how to do  - will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a project named **MyApp.UI** and create one folder for each project you want to merge, in your example i'd create this 4 folders: **Design**, **Design.Themes**, **Design.Controllers** and **Design.xyz**.

Comment: Then put each class in its respective folder with its respective namespace.

Comment: But what about Assembly Name how to configure Assembly and namespace. in this scenario you described about making folder but what about namespace and base assembly

Comment: Creating a single project will produce a single assembly. Miltiple namespaces can exist into a single assembly. If your project is named MyApp.UI, the dll related will be called as well.

Comment: In one hand you have the phisical distribution and libraries, in this case it is the MyApp.UI assembly, on the other hand you have the logical distribution, It is composed by your namespaces and folders and clases. I'm guessing that what you want is to join 4 separated dlls into one, isnt it?

Comment: What if Some Don't Modules Don't Have Same Base NameSpace

Comment: In that case dafault namespace will be the name of the project/assembly

Comment: actually not only 4 total 27 right now few are with same Base NameSpace few are 2 different base names

Comment: is there any examples available online for reference, i tried to search but not found even one

Comment: Ok, If the some dlls share namespace there is no problem, the problem will raise if you find two (or more) classes with the same name! In that case there isn't a simple solution.
Add to the questions some examples of what the structure is

Comment: is there any online reference projects or documents to check. still little bit confused.